# msbuild of a vc++ solution cleaning project after already built using VS2015 projects and solujtions

Tags: c++, makefile, tfs, msbuild

I've been redesigning my custom VC++ build to be compatible with the new TFS 2015 Build solution.

The issue is running msbuild.  I can post perhaps a simplified version, but my solution contains two items:

1 Makefile Project designed to build all of the libraries required, and
1 .exe project.

I have a reference in the .exe project to the makefile project, so that the build of the .exe forces the build of the library if needed.

The issue we are seeing is that when we do a rebuild with msbuild of the solution, it first rebuilds the library, and then when it gets to the .exe, it cleans the library project, causing some of the rebuilt files to be deleted and then preventing the link of the .exe file because the .lib file was deleted.

Why is it cleaning the makefile project again? It seems like when it gets to the .exe project, it re-resolves the dependency, and does not know that the library project was already rebuilt.

Thanks in advance.   Larry

Comment: So you run `msbuild some.sln /t:Rebuild`, and that results in clean M/build M/clean M/clean E/build E (where M stands for Makefile project and E for exe project? Exactly those steps?

Comment: We get a M/Rebuild, then when it got to the .exe project, it did a M/Clean, M/Build, then E/Rebuild.

Comment: That doesn't seem to reflect one of the things you state in the question: if M/Build comes before E/Rebuild, how can E still have linking problems, after M has been built?

Comment: Our issue is that it is actually rebuilding the M project again (via Clean and Build) when it gets to the exe project.   Rebuild is different for us than clean and build, rebuild has some additional requirements.  Our optimal solution is for never doing anything to the M project after it's first rebuild.  We will be doing a multi-processor build and there will eventually be over 1000 E's.

Comment: By the way, devenv seems to work differently.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple projects are in the same folder, Visual Studio attempts to erase output folder (typically Debug or Release) when the next project will be compiled.  The best solution is to put each project in the separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go through all details but the reason this happens is that when building on the command-line, rebuilding the exe project results in Clean + Build of the exe project, and the Clean target for the exe project eventually calls the `CleanReferencedProjects` Target which results in Clean being called on your Makefile project (and later on, Build as well).

This CleanReferencedProjects is conditional on the properties `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` and `BuildProjectReferences`, so building inside VS skips this step anyway because BuildingInsideVisualStudio is true, and it's even documented:

> When building the project directly from the command-line, clean those referenced projects
>   that exist on disk.  For IDE builds and command-line .SLN builds, the solution build manager
>   takes care of this.

The BuildProjectReferences property is documented as follows:

> By default we will build (and if applicable, clean) all project references. But this can be used to disable that

So one possible solution is calling `msbuild some.sln /t:Rebuild /p:BuildProjectReferences=False`. In the case with only 2 projects this will work properly, but I cannot guarantee this will always work in more complicated situations with more inter-project dependencies.

Now one thing got me wondering: how come I've never seen this behaviour myself? The answer lies in that I don't use makefile projects often, and the C++ projects which I do use are slightly different: there, the Rebuid target is defined in terms of Clean+Build (while for a Makefile project it is a standalone, separate target). As such when the exe project calls BuildProjectReferences, it will call Clean in the C++ project, but that results in

```
Target "Clean" skipped. Previously built successfully.
```

because when the C++ project's Rebuild was called it called Clean and Build already.

So another possible solution is doing the same for the Makefile project. You say that your Rebuild has additional requirements; I don't know what they are nor why they are needed (and arguably it is wrong that Rebuild does not have the same effect as Clean + Build) but this might work anyway, for example with this in the makefile project (all the way at the end of the file):

```
<Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build">
  <!--additional requirements here perhaps?-->
</Target>
```

everything beaves properly and Clean/Build is called once only.

If none of these solutions apply I don't immediately see another way than removing the makefile project from the solution, and manually building it before the solution both locally and in TFS.